# How parquet stores timestamp data in S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, timestamp, parquet, amazon-athena

I have my data stored in S3 in file_name.snappy.parquet format. when I preview this file in S3 I get my timestamp field as:
`{"ModifiedOn": 4.535976891407963e+25}`

this field is created using pyspark TimestampType. when I see this field in Athena table it shows as `2020-04-18 21:55:41.000`, as expected. But when I try to convert it manually I get `Monday, May 25, 3407 7:48:34.079 AM`. (using https://www.epochconverter.com/ ) 
Assuming that this timestamp is in nanoseconds (1 billionth of a second).

How can I get correct date for given field manually?

Answer (score 0):

Took me awhile to find this solution as well. The datetime returned is in INT96 format. To convert it back to a julian calendar date, follow this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58154815/1733222.