# How can I write Parquet files with int64 timestamps (instead of int96) from AWS Kinesis Firehose?

Tags: hive, aws-glue, parquet, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-s3-select

### Why do int96 timestamps not work for me?

I want to read the Parquet files with S3 Select. S3 Select does not support timestamps saved as int96 according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-data-types.html#s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-supported-data-types). Also, storing timestamps in parquet as int96 is [deprecated](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-323).

### What did I try?

Firehose uses `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe` for serialization to parquet. (The exact hive version that is used by AWS is unknown.) While reading the hive code, I came across the following config switch: [`hive.parquet.write.int64.timestamp`](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/common/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf.java#L2267). I tried to apply this config switch by changing the Serde parameters in the AWS Glue table config:
[image: AWS Glue Serde parameters config]
Unfortunately, this did not make a difference and my timestamp column is still stored as int96 (checked by downloading a file from S3 and inspecting it with `parq my-file.parquet --schema`)

Comment: Apparently firehose uses `parquet-mr version 1.8.1` to write the parquet files. (Revealed by the output of `parquet-tools meta` for one of the parquet files.) As a side note: Athena uses a more recent version `parquet-mr version 1.11.1-amzn-athena-1`.

Answer (score 0):

While I was not able to make Firehose write int64 timestamps, I found a workaround to convert the int96 timestamps returned by the S3 Select query result into something useful.

I used the approach described in

- [How parquet stores timestamp data in S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61392662/2584278)
- [boto 3 - loosing date format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58151239/2584278)

to write the following conversion function in JavaScript:

```
const hideTimePart = BigInt(64);
const maskToHideJulianDayPart = BigInt('0xffffffffffffffff');
const unixEpochInJulianDay = 2_440_588;
const nanoSecsInOneSec = BigInt(1_000_000_000);
const secsInOneDay = 86_400;
const milliSecsInOneSec = 1_000;

export const parseS3SelectParquetTimeStamp = (ts: string) => {
  const tsBigInt = BigInt(ts);

  const julianDay = Number(tsBigInt >> hideTimePart);
  const secsSinceUnixEpochToStartOfJulianDay = (julianDay - unixEpochInJulianDay) * secsInOneDay;

  const nanoSecsSinceStartOfJulianDay = tsBigInt & maskToHideJulianDayPart;
  const secsSinceStartOJulianDay = Number(nanoSecsSinceStartOfJulianDay / nanoSecsInOneSec);

  return new Date(
    (secsSinceUnixEpochToStartOfJulianDay + secsSinceStartOJulianDay) * milliSecsInOneSec,
  );
};

parseS3SelectParquetTimeStamp('45377606915595481758988800'); // Result: '2022-12-11T20:58:33.000Z'
```

Note, [unlike expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53104516/2584278), the timestamps returned by S3 Select stores the julian day part **at the beginning** and not in the last 4 bytes. The nano sec time part is stored in the last 8 bytes. Furthermore, the byte order is **not reversed**.

(Regarding the julian day constant `2440588`: Using `2440587.5` would be wrong in this context according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/JulianFields.html)